# Bundle: `require': cannot load such file -- thread/pool (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, bundler

I am having issue with this code called CiscoBruter (https://github.com/R3dy/ciscobruter/) when trying to run it I get these errors.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- thread/pool (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from ./ciscobruter.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

When running 'bundle install' this is the code

```
  Fetching git://github.com/meh/ruby-thread.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...
Using hitimes 1.2.4
Using coderay 1.1.1
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using slop 3.6.0
Using ruby-progressbar 1.8.1
Using thread 0.2.2 from git://github.com/meh/ruby-thread.git (at master@d0e99c2)
Using bundler 1.12.5
Using timers 4.1.1
Using pry 0.10.4
Using celluloid-essentials 0.20.5
Using celluloid-extras 0.20.5
Using celluloid-fsm 0.20.5
Using celluloid-pool 0.20.5
Using celluloid-supervision 0.20.6
Using celluloid 0.17.3
Bundle complete! 4 Gemfile dependencies, 15 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
root@HaroonB-HomeUbuntu:/var/www/DisHack/ciscobruter# bundle sho
Gems included by the bundle:
  * bundler (1.12.5)
  * celluloid (0.17.3)
  * celluloid-essentials (0.20.5)
  * celluloid-extras (0.20.5)
  * celluloid-fsm (0.20.5)
  * celluloid-pool (0.20.5)
  * celluloid-supervision (0.20.6)
  * coderay (1.1.1)
  * hitimes (1.2.4)
  * method_source (0.8.2)
  * pry (0.10.4)
  * ruby-progressbar (1.8.1)
  * slop (3.6.0)
  * thread (0.2.2 d0e99c2)
  * timers (4.1.1)
```

Please could someone help me and explain what I'm doing wrongly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `thread/pool` definitely exists here https://github.com/meh/ruby-thread/blob/master/lib/thread/pool.rb and you have the thread gem being installed. Note that the gem is not being tested against Ruby 2.3 though, so it may be incompatible.

Comment: Thank you so much Matt! I installed it and it works fully. :)

Comment: You installed what?

Comment: I did "gem install thread" and then "gem install pool". And it worked.

Comment: Right, but you already had them installed with bundler. Is this a bundler error?

Comment: Yes. It is as I had to install it manually. This is fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed! By running these commands

```
gem install thread
```

And

```
gem install pool
```